# Set appid, appsecret of omniauth-facebook gem dynamically based on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

Each customer in our ror app is served based on subdomain and they have their fbappid, fbsecretid (whichi powers the customers fb app).  We use omniauth, omniauth-facebook for authenticating users.
so customer1.ourapp.com serves an fb app with appid fbapp_1 and 
   customer2.ourapp.com server with appid fbapp_2

normal way of initialization of facebook strategy is putting the following line in a initializer

```
config.omniauth :facebook, APP_ID, SECRET, {:scope => 'publish_stream}
```

We need to set APP_ID, SECRET based on the subdomain, but it looks like request object is not avaiable at the initializer time
I looked into the dynamic setting of options using setup=> but omniauth-facebook doesnt seem to support setting of appid, appsecret dynamically.

How do we set the app_id and app_secret of omniauth-facebook dynamically based on subdomain of the request?  thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using devise, try

```
config.omniauth  :facebook, :setup => lambda{
      current_domain = // Get current domain
      config = // Get config
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = config[current_domain][Rails.env]["app_id"]
      env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = config[current_domain][Rails.env]["app_secret"]
    }
```

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:zmBqDAomJ84J:blog.cedricbousmanne.com/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk
provides the solution without devise, with just omniauth

[edited]
Excerpt from working code

```
config.omniauth :facebook, {:setup => lambda{|env|
   env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_id] = $institute_tenant.fbappid
   env['omniauth.strategy'].options[:client_secret] = $institute_tenant.fbappsecret
}, :auth_type => 'https', :scope => 'email'}
```

Comment: This does not work, config.omniauth :facebook expects two more arguments (devise 1.4.9)

Comment: @Victor hope this answers your question?